# Avoiding the use of with activesheet in this code

Tags: vba, excel

I've received some really great help on here for writing a short macro as shown below (which works perfectly).

The issue I'm having is I don't understand how I can remove the constant with `ActiveSheet` at every step. Ideally I'd like to be able to run the macro from my personal macro workbook on sheets with different names.

Also, any pointers on how I could improve this would be greatly received, I don't have to do this sort of thing often, but I would still like to improve, and hours of internet searching on this seems to have me going round and round in circles.

Thanks as always for taking the time to look.

```
  Sub SheetFormat()

 Dim lr         As Long
 Dim cl         As Range
 Dim rng        As Range
 Dim mssg       As String

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'cleans all non_printable characters from the data (excluding invoice_date, effective_date and spare_date)
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = Union(.Range("C2:AA" & lr), .Range("AM2:AM" & lr), .Range("AD2:AO" & lr))
        For Each cl In rng
        cl.Value = WorksheetFunction.Clean(cl.Value)

        Next cl
    End With

    'removes additional spaces from the client_name and comment field
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = Union(.Range("I2:I" & lr), .Range("AM2:AM" & lr))
        For Each cl In rng
        cl.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(cl.Value)

        Next cl
    End With

    'truncates comments field to 500 characters
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("AM2:AM" & lr)
        For Each cl In rng
        cl.Value = Left(cl.Value, 500)

        Next cl
    End With

    'format invoice_date, effective_date & spare_date to dd/mm/yyyy
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = Union(.Range("AB2:AB" & lr), .Range("AC2:AC" & lr), .Range("AP2:AP" & lr))
        For Each cl In rng
        cl.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

        Next cl
    End With

    'formats all numerical fields to "0.00"
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = Union(.Range("AD2:AL" & lr), .Range("AO2:AO" & lr))
        For Each cl In rng
        cl.NumberFormat = "0.00"

        Next cl
    End With

    'checks that only date values as present in the invoice_date, effective_date & spare_date
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = Union(.Range("AB2:AB" & lr), .Range("AC2:AC" & lr), .Range("AP2:AP" & lr))
        For Each cl In rng
            If Not IsDate(cl.Value) And Not IsEmpty(cl) Then _
                mssg = mssg & cl.Address(0, 0) & Space(4)
        Next cl
    End With
    If CBool(Len(mssg)) Then
        MsgBox ("There are invalid date value(s) in the following cells: " & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
          mssg & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
          "Please correct and re-run the macro")
    Else
        MsgBox "Statement Preperation Is Complete"
    End If

    Set rng = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are doing this from the add-in then i would recommend keeping it as `activesheet` else you will have to keep on changing the name of the sheet like shown in the answer below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest problem you have is looping which should be kept to a minimum. Many of those operations could be nested together so that the cells are only looped through once rather than several times for individual operations. Others require no loop at all. For example:

```
Sub SheetFormat()

    Dim lr         As Long
    Dim cl         As Range
    Dim rng        As Range
    Dim mssg       As String
    Dim ws         As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ActiveSheet    'could be activeworkbook.sheets("Sheet2") or something

    With ws
        'cleans all non_printable characters from the data (excluding invoice_date, effective_date and spare_date)
        'trim and truncate added here
        lr = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = Union(.Range("C2:AA" & lr), .Range("AD2:AO" & lr), .Range("AM2:AM" & lr))
        For Each cl In rng
            If cl.Column = 39 Then 'column AM gets Left() truncation as well
                cl = Left(WorksheetFunction.Trim(WorksheetFunction.Clean(cl.Value)), 500)
            Else
                cl = WorksheetFunction.Trim(WorksheetFunction.Clean(cl.Value))
            End If
        Next cl

        'format invoice_date, effective_date & spare_date to dd/mm/yyyy
        Union(.Range("AB2:AB" & lr), .Range("AC2:AC" & lr), .Range("AP2:AP" & lr)).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

        'formats all numerical fields to "0.00"
        Union(.Range("AD2:AL" & lr), .Range("AO2:AO" & lr)).NumberFormat = "0.00"

        'checks that only date values as present in the invoice_date, effective_date & spare_date
        Set rng = Union(.Range("AB2:AB" & lr), .Range("AC2:AC" & lr), .Range("AP2:AP" & lr))
        For Each cl In rng
            If Not IsDate(cl.Value) And Not IsEmpty(cl) Then _
                mssg = mssg & cl.Address(0, 0) & Space(4)
        Next cl
    End With

    If CBool(Len(mssg)) Then
        MsgBox ("There are invalid date value(s) in the following cells: " & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
          mssg & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & _
          "Please correct and re-run the macro")
    Else
        MsgBox "Statement Preparation Is Complete"
    End If

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

So some of those looping operations were able to be handled *en masse* and others could be nested together so the loops weren't repeated. Other operations like the date examination really does need to be on a cell-by-cell basis and was left alone. The assignment of *lr* to the maximum number of rows only needed to be done once.

Comment: This is great, allows me to still use the ActiveSheet and also removes the need to keep repeating it. Cutting down the number of loops was an extra really helpful touch - the loops looked inefficient but I didn't think of evaluating more than one at a time. Thanks for the first bit of help, and with this, will study your answer and learn for the future.